# can't capture browser log using python, selenium and phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, yocto

I have been working on Python, Selenium and phantomjs and i got stuck with error

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://google.com')
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print entry
```

this is the sample code i'm using, the problem is it is working perfectly in ubuntu and raspberry pi but when i try the same code in Toradex borad(T30) which has yocto linux.
i get an error stating

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1238, in get_log
    return self.execute(Command.GET_LOG, {'type': log_type})['value']   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 208, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value) 
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Invalid Command Method - Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"71","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:42648","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"sessionId\": \"db7d3690-6a59-11e8-bf9a-d526e0e5f7cd\", \"type\": \"server\"}","url":"/log","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"log","directory":"/","path":"/log","relative":"/log","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/log","queryKey":{},"chunks":["log"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/db7d3690-6a59-11e8-bf9a-d526e0e5f7cd/log"}
```

can anyone help me or guide me where i went wrong in the process.
i'm using python = 2.7,
          phantomjs = 1.9.0 and selenium = 3.9

My ultimate goal is to capture the console log of browser any alternative approaches to this will be very helpful, i got the desired output in raspberry pi but i got stuck here in toradex board which has yocto in it.

Comment: for testing better don't use `google`

Comment: @zimdero thank you for the quick response, i have tried different sites for testing and ever time i end up getting the same error as `invalid command method`